# Meteor {{yield}} not rendering in right place with Boostrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor

The `{{yield}}` portion of my page isn't rendering right with my bootstrap layout. It's behaving as if it's simply appended to the body rather than inserted into the right place.

Here's the relevant part of my template:

```html
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
                    ...
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-9">
                {{yield}}
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                    {{> sideNav}}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

<template name="home">
    <p>Home Ya'll.</p>
</template>
```

Everything's working fine, and the `home` template is being rendered, but it's being rendered basically like this:

```html
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">...</div>
    <p>Home ya'll.</p> <!-- This should be inside the div -->
</body>
```

with the `home` template portion *after* the `div` instead of *inside* it. What's going on?

If it matters, I'm including bootstrap with [this less enabled package](https://github.com/zeroasterisk/bootstrap3-less).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated right at the beginning of the official docs at https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router#concepts

> Iron-router takes over generating the `<body>` of the page. You won't need to define the `<body>` element as you would for HTML pages; rather, you define a `"layout"` (usually a `<template name="layout">...</template>`, which contains static elements that don't change across pages of the app, and also one or more `{{yield}}` tags (technically template helpers), which will bring in content from other templates. In a layout file, the `{{yield}}` tag without any parameters is called the `"main yield"`, and it will pull in the route template specified by the template option of the `route()` method call.

According to this, instead of making the body your main template, just wrap that in a layout template

```
<template name="layout">
  {{yield}}
</template>
```

and declare the template name as your main layout in your route configuration.

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout'
});
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed that!

Comment: Perfectly normal when there is so much to dig in :)

Comment: Let me ask you this: is it possible to do nested routes? To have one global layout template, but then also embed child routes in their own layouts?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router#using-a-layout-with-yields specifically the `yieldTemplates` code. Is this perhaps what you are looking for?